# how do you add a segment of a list

Tags: list, python-2.7

I try to get the sum of `lines2[4]`. Here is the program

```
barcode = int(raw_input("\nenter product's GTIN-8 barcode\n>>>"))
main(barcode)
def main(product): 
    textfile=open("stock.txt","r")
    quantity=int(raw_input("enetr quantity\n>>>>"))
    for lines in textfile:
        br,pd,pr=lines.split(",")
        if int(br)==int(product):
            price=float(quantity)*float(pr)
            lines2=[product,pd,pr,quantity,"%.2f"%price]
            print sum(map(int,lines2[4]))`
```

The error I keep getting is

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '.'

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to use `int()` on a floating point number.
Stating `"%.2f"` generates a float as a string meaning it contains a "." character.

Try replacing the last line: `print sum(map(int,lines2[4]))` with `print sum(map(float,lines2[4]))`

Comment: Never mind realized what i did wrong. Just needed to append to a separate list. OOPS